# What is the category limit for category widgets in CARTO BUILDER?

Tags: carto

Is there a way to set the numbers of items displayed in the category widget? Is 5 the current limit?

I can not find anything in the documentation:
https://carto.com/learn/guides/widgets/search-and-filter-category-values

I can use "Search in categories" but then the items are not selectable anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, 5 is the limit of categories displayed on a BUILDER category widget. But you should be able to select categories using the "Search" option.

Comment: @ramiroaznar I think you answered the question, please move the comment to the answer so we can mark it as valid

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, 5 is the limit of categories displayed on a BUILDER category widget. But you should be able to select categories using the "Search" option.